# IE, getElementById, and radio buttons

Tags: internet-explorer, radio-button, getelementbyid

Some simple code:

```
<input type="radio" id="knob-reassign-leave" name="knob-reassign" value="n" checked="checked">Leave <br>
<input type="radio" id="knob-reassign-cmp" name="knob-reassign" value="d"> Default <br>
<input type="radio" id="knob-reassign" name="knob-reassign" value="r"> Reassign to

<select name="assigned_to" id="assigned_to" onchange="
  if ((this.value != 'currentuser') && (this.value != '')) {
    var kr = document.getElementById('knob-reassign');
    document.getElementById('knob-reassign').checked=true;
  }">

  <option value="otheruser">Someone Else</option>
  <option value="lastuser">Someone Third</option>
  <option value="currentuser" selected="selected">Me</option>
</select>
```

This all works very well in FF and chrome, but as I always hear when I write code, this doesn't work in IE.  It appears that IE is searching 'names' for the ID, or it tries to translate the ID into a name, because it always selects the first radio, when it should grab the last.

Comment: I just tested and it selects the last radio button for me.

Comment: Which browser and version?  I'm using IE 8.0.6001.18702 with compatibility mode off, and it selects the wrong radio every time.

Comment: Turning compatibility mode on doesn't change the behavior. I am using EXACTLY the code I've posted above.  Prefixing the ID's with id- fixes my problem, but isn't what I want to have to do to get proper behavior.

Comment: Your onchange script is horrible at this location (not being able to get it syntax-highlighted in most editors is just one reason). Move it to a function in <script> tags or an external file.

Comment: ThiefMaster, It isn't my code originally, I'm just trying to fix it.  moving it to <script> tags isn't going to solve that.

Comment: IE 8.0.7600.16385. http://kaitnieks.com/Document2.htm

Comment: haha:This Web site is in a category that represents a potential information security risk to the Corporation and has been blocked by Corporate Information Security. 

Blocked URL: http://kaitnieks.com/Document2.htm 
Category: Hacking;Games;Newsgroups/Forums

Comment: @meagar: I have a test.html file with only the code above.  It picks the wrong button in IE 8.0.6001.18702.  Maybe 8.0.7600... works better.

Comment: Wow, seriosuly? Still? I made RuneScape cheats years ago and they still block me? I don't know where else to host it :(

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Not my code: http://mxr.mozilla.org/bugzilla3.0/source/template/en/default/bug/knob.html.tmpl#92

Comment: Ah, there's your problem. You need XHTML doctype for it to work.

Comment: You'd think that I wouldn't need XHTML, and could just use getElementById to select an input element by its id attribute.  I guess MS didn't have it correct in the build for XP...

Comment: If you don't specify doctype, it uses the very specific Microsoft implementation of HTML4 in which you're lucky if anything works at all...

Answer (score 0):

IE6/7/8 do indeed seem to select the first `<input>` element when the name and ID are the same. Here is a simple test case:

```
<input type="radio" id="a" name="c" value="1">
<input type="radio" id="b" name="c" value="2">
<input type="radio" id="c" name="c" value="3">

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Should get 3rd <input> with id 'c' and alert '3'
    // Instead finds 1st input with name 'c' and alerts '1'
    alert(document.getElementById('c').value); 
</script>
```

While I can't offer an explanation ([Google has tons of relevant results](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ie+getElementById+returns+name)), I can offer a fix: Either [override IE's implementation of getElementById](http://www.sixteensmallstones.org/ie-javascript-bugs-overriding-internet-explorers-documentgetelementbyid-to-be-w3c-compliant-exposes-an-additional-bug-in-getattributes) or change the ID of the last element to be different from the name:

```
<input type="radio" id="knob-reassign-leave" name="knob-reassign" value="n" checked="checked">Leave <br>
<input type="radio" id="knob-reassign-cmp" name="knob-reassign" value="d"> Default <br>
<input type="radio" id="knob-reassign-reassign" name="knob-reassign" value="r"> Reassign to

<select name="assigned_to" id="assigned_to" onchange="
  if ((this.value != 'currentuser') && (this.value != '')) {
    document.getElementById('knob-reassign-reassign').checked=true;
  }">

  <option value="otheruser">Someone Else</option>
  <option value="lastuser">Someone Third</option>
  <option value="currentuser" selected="selected">Me</option>
</select>
```